How to fill and format DataGridView asynchronously?
I am trying to fill and format a DataGridView asynchronously. I am using .Net 7.
The data to be fed to the DGV is retrieved asynchronously from a MySQL query. The DGV in some cases can be quite large and having 10k+ rows and about 150 columns. Usually the filling with data takes less time, but formatting some of the columns with specific backcolors and all of the columns with different widths takes more time. The whole process freezes the UI of the complete application (the same WinForm or another one, which the user browses asynchronously in parallel).
So my idea is to transfer the code below to run fully asynchronously without any UI blockings if it is possible at all.
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim TabStats As New DataTable
    'Other async code for filling the table from MySQL query

    DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
    DataGridView1.DataSource = TabStats

    DataGridView1.Columns(0).Width = 80
    DataGridView1.Columns(1).Width = 80
    DataGridView1.Columns(2).Width = 80

    DataGridView1.Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue
    DataGridView1.Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue
    DataGridView1.Columns(2).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue
End Sub

What I have tried is below. I created a Sub for DGV manipulation and wrapped it in Async Task. Unfortunatelly the UI is blocked again the same way as it happens with the code above.
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim TabStats As New DataTable
    'Other async code for filling the table from MySQL query

    Await Task.Run(Sub() Me.Invoke(Sub() fillDgv(DataGridView1, TabStats)))
End Sub

Private Sub fillDgv(dgv As DataGridView, tab As DataTable)
    dgv.DataSource = Nothing
    dgv.DataSource = tab

    dgv.Columns(0).Width = 80
    dgv.Columns(1).Width = 80
    dgv.Columns(2).Width = 80

    dgv.Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue
    dgv.Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue
    dgv.Columns(2).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue
End Sub

Any help will be appreciated.

Loading up the DGV with hundreds of rows is often problematic. Have a look at VirtualMode: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode?view=windowsdesktop-8.0

A quicker option is to lock the dgv to a certain number of rows (e.g. 50) and require the user to click Previous and Next buttons to see the next page of results

Instead of formatting the columns after binding the data, add the columns in the designer and do all the formatting there. If everything is already in place when you set the DataSource, you won't be doing loads of redundant work at that point.

150 columns in a result set? How could the users even use that?

@SSS I know about VirtualMode but will need to further research it. I am not sure how VirtualMode will deal when the user is doing sorting by different columns and what happens when the contents of the complete DGV is being exported.

@jmcilhinney Your proposal sounds interesting. An issue could be that depending on user choice there can be two more or two less columns, meaning that the column number is not fixed at design time. Will give it a try.

@HardCode Very easy. But I will not continue this discussion.

You can hide and show columns at run time so I would expect it would still be more efficient to add them all at design time and then just hide those you don't need before binding, reshowing them later if required.

jmcilhinney's suggestion above is a good one. Set up your DataGridView properties before you bind DataSource. Below example sets the properties in code, but you can also use the designer instead.
There are two buttons that bind different DataTables, to demonstrate that the grid formatting survives a refresh of the DataSource.
Public Class Form1

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Col1", "Column one")
    DataGridView1.Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "Col1"
    DataGridView1.Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
    DataGridView1.Columns(0).Width = 80

    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Col2", "Column two")
    DataGridView1.Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "Col2"
    DataGridView1.Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue
    DataGridView1.Columns(1).Width = 70

    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Col2", "Column three")
    DataGridView1.Columns(2).DataPropertyName = "Col3"
    DataGridView1.Columns(2).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.CadetBlue
    DataGridView1.Columns(2).Width = 60

  End Sub

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dtb As New DataTable
    dtb.Columns.Add("Col1")
    dtb.Columns.Add("Col2")
    dtb.Columns.Add("Col3")
    dtb.Rows.Add("1", "2", "3")
    dtb.Rows.Add("4", "5", "6")
    dtb.Rows.Add("7", "8", "9")

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dtb
  End Sub

  Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim dtb As New DataTable
    dtb.Columns.Add("Col1")
    dtb.Columns.Add("Col2")
    dtb.Columns.Add("Col3")
    dtb.Rows.Add("a", "b", "c")
    dtb.Rows.Add("d", "e", "f")
    dtb.Rows.Add("g", "h", "i")

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dtb
  End Sub
End Class


The main idea of my question is why DGV data binding and formating process does not act asynchronously and is blocking the UI. I am still not sure whether this is possible at all. In my opinion the drawback of your solution regarding my specific case is that the columns of my DGV are not always the same number and the exact number depends on a few options, which the user selects. So pre-formatting might be not working properly. I will test that. Still I have a few DGVs with fixed columns, whether I can use your solution. Will test it and will come back to you.

Your solution is working flawlessly. I can confirm that the formatting survives any kind of tests that I performed. Like this the time for binding and formatting is reduced by a half. Unfortunately I cannot accept your post as an answer, because my question was for asynchronous process. Pre-formatting speeds up the process, so no Async is needed for it, but I still can't find a way to make databinding asynchronous.

Regarding the different number of columns in DGV based on the user choice I made following. The fixed part of columns, which is the majority is added to the DGV and formatted during form loading. Then depending on user selection I am adding and removing the header columns, which are positioned in the beginning, so this is an easy operation.
